# Make child element full horizontal width of scrolling parent

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to tweak an existing app so would prefer to not change the dom structure. But I can't seem to get it how I need.

here is the example of where I am now.

https://codepen.io/m1nd/pen/QYLMeJ

```
<div class="canvas">
  <div class="node node-1">node 1</div>
  <div class="node node-2">node 2</div>
  <div class="node node-3">node 3</div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="right-target"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
  background: yellow;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.canvas {
  position:relative;
  background: red;
  height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
}

.node {
  position:absolute;
  background: grey;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
}

.node-1 {
  top: 2px;
  left: 2000px;
}

.wrapper {
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
  background:pink;
}

.right-target {
  position:absolute;
  right:0px;
  top:0px;
  width:20px;
  height: 100%;
  background:green;
}
```

I want the .wrapper div to expand to the full width of the .canvas (scrolling) div, so the green .right-target should be to the far  far right.But no matter what I try I can't seem to get the .wrapper div to expand past the viewport width.

I've seen examples that address this vertically (http://bennadel.github.io/JavaScript-Demos/demos/css-position-overflow/) but I can't seem to get the same principle to work in my case.

Comment: Giving a hard width to the .canvas element will fix the issue. 

The examples you include work because the container is given a hard width and height. Also the HTML structure is different than yours.

Comment: so its not possible with a fluid width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options...

1. Make the .wrapper overflow the viewport by the exact width of its child element, which is what you actually want to out of the viewport, but this will be near impossible to do precisely (without some extremely new CSS features) becaaus you will have make that .wrapped element `100% + 20px` wide (this is actually on the future specs I believe)
2. A better solution, if it works for your use case, would be having the green .right-target overlap is container (.wrapper) by its exact width...

   `.right-target {
       ...
       right: -20px;
       ...
   }`

Sorry, misunderstood question. Revised answer below...

To do this you will need to use Javascript since the .canvas element is overflowing the viewport. You'll need to...

1. Calculate initial viewport width
2. Imperatively set the `.canvas` width to the viewport width + the offset of the element creating the overflow, `.node-1` and `2000px` respectively

   3. On resize of the viewport you will have to re-calculate the new viewport.
   4. reset the `.canvas` to the new viewport width + the same `.node-1` offset

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
var viewportStartWidth = window.outerWidth,
    $target = $('.wrapper'),
    $offsetElems = $('.canvas .node'),
    offsetRight = (function () {
       var largestOffset = 0;
       $offsetElems.each(function(){
            var pos = $(this).offset().left;
            if (pos > largestOffset) {
             largestOffset = pos; 
            }
       });
       return largestOffset;
    })();
  
$target.width(viewportStartWidth + offsetRight)

$(window).on('resize', function(){
  var viewportNewWidth= $(this).outerWidth;
  $target.width(viewportNewWidth + offsetRight)
});

})
```

This makes you code very brittle though (if `2000px` offset ever changes) and also has a significant performance cost (calculating and resetting width) every browser resize. You can improve this by debouncing/rate-limiting these calculations, but I would suggest a solution that ***does*** reorganize the DOM instead, even if you have to do it with JS on initial page load.

Full working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QYWwKq

This is the only way you're able to do it with pure CSS, but take a look at the [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) to make sure it is acceptable for you...

```
.canvas {
    ...
    width: calc(100% + 2000px);   
    ...
}
```

Working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GzRgeE

Comment: maybe i'm misunderstanding, but I don't think this will help in this case. https://codepen.io/m1nd/pen/XOWWoE (example of moving the target -20). The pink should be overlapping the entire red section

Comment: Ok maybe I must have misunderstood. Do you want it to be positioned all the way to the right of 'red' element?

Comment: yea essentially trying to get the pink element .wrapper to expand to the full width of .canvas. Then the green .right-target should be the further most right.

Comment: PS I have no idea why my inline editor is so screwy, I'm so sick of this thing!!

Comment: Oh ya, and I just updated the solution. Let me know if this is the result youre looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This was going to be my fallback approach if I couldn't get it to work with just css alone.

Comment: Ok, well I just added the 'future css' solution so take a look at that as well. Much more performant and I'm actually surprised how good browser support is.

Comment: the only prob is my example offset of 2000px could be any value in the real application. so would still need javascript to pull this value (sorry should have specified that in the original question)

Comment: Ah ok, yup you're stuck with JS then. You're welcome to wait around for another solution, but I'm 99% sure this is the extent of your options, without reorganizing the DOM. I appreciate the 'upvote', but if this is your 'accepted' solution then would you mind marking it as so (green check-mark)?

Comment: Let me know if theres anything else I can help with!

Comment: yep will give it a green tick if no other solutions come in today. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it, and no problem, happy to help. I just updated the JS solution to check for the `.node` with largest offset on page load and use that as your `.canvas` offset.